# Colored arcs on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to draw sectors with different colors and radiuses. So I write some code using canvas.arc and fill methods

```
// constants & vars
var data=[0.2, 0.5, .5, 1.0, 0.8, .9, .7, .8];
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "gray", "orange", 
            "rgb(255,165,0)", "rgb(100,100,100)", "black"];
var WIDTH = 200; 
var HEIGHT = 200;
var centralPoint = {x:WIDTH/2, y:HEIGHT/2};
var radius=HEIGHT/2;
var sectorsCount = data.length;
var epsilon=0.0001;
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("graphic"),
    ctx     = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    myCanvas.height=HEIGHT;
    myCanvas.width=WIDTH;

//drawing
    for (var i=0; i<sectorsCount-1;i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(centralPoint.x, centralPoint.y);
        ctx.fillStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 
            radius*data[i], 
            i*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount+epsilon , 
            (i+1)*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount-epsilon,
             false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
```

The problem is when next sector is drawing, previous one change color too. So at the end I have sectors with different radius but with the same (last) color.

Possibly there is more simple way to do the same stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path drawing commands begin with `context.beginPath` and remain in effect until the next `context.beginPath`. So without a new beginPath all of your previous wedges will be redrawn with the last wedge.

So the simple fix is to make sure each of your wedges begin with `beginPath`:

```js
var data=[0.2, 0.5, .5, 1.0, 0.8, .9, .7, .8];
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "gray", "orange", "rgb(255,165,0)", "rgb(100,100,100)", "black"];
var WIDTH = 200; 
var HEIGHT = 200;
var centralPoint = {x:WIDTH/2, y:HEIGHT/2};
var radius=HEIGHT/2;
var sectorsCount = data.length;
var epsilon=0.0001;
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("graphic"),
    ctx     = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
myCanvas.height=HEIGHT;
myCanvas.width=WIDTH;

//drawing
for (var i=0; i<sectorsCount-1;i++) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(centralPoint.x, centralPoint.y);
  ctx.fillStyle=colors[i];
  ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 
          radius*data[i], 
          i*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount+epsilon , 
          (i+1)*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount-epsilon,
          false);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}
ctx.fillStyle="black";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<canvas id="graphic" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `beginPath()` before drawing the new arc:

```
for (var i=0; i<sectorsCount-1;i++) {
    ctx.beginPath();     // <--- needs beginPath() here
    ctx.moveTo(centralPoint.x, centralPoint.y);
```

What happens if not is that path objects are accumulated. The next time a fill/stroke is used, all paths objects are filled/stroked. This happens independent on clearing the canvas, so the path needs to be cleared using the `beginPath()`.

Hope this helps - see update below:

```js
// constants & vars
var data=[0.2, 0.5, .5, 1.0, 0.8, .9, .7, .8];
var colors=["red", "blue", "green", "gray", "orange", "rgb(255,165,0)", "rgb(100,100,100)", "black"];
var WIDTH = 200; 
var HEIGHT = 200;
var centralPoint = {x:WIDTH/2, y:HEIGHT/2};
var radius=HEIGHT/2;
var sectorsCount = data.length;
var epsilon=0.0001;
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("graphic"),
    ctx     = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
    myCanvas.height=HEIGHT;
    myCanvas.width=WIDTH;

//drawing
    for (var i=0; i<sectorsCount-1;i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(centralPoint.x, centralPoint.y);
        ctx.fillStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 
            radius*data[i], 
            i*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount+epsilon , 
            (i+1)*2*Math.PI/sectorsCount-epsilon,
             false);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    ctx.fillStyle="black";
    ctx.arc(centralPoint.x,centralPoint.y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="graphic" />
```

Comment: thanks, it solved my problem! I can't mark both answers as solved, sorry )